# Execute for loop every 20ms

Tags: java

I would like to execute a for loop that looks like this:

```
        int incAmt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Double.parseDouble(arguements[0]); i += 0.9) {
            // Wait 20ms
            // do stuff
            // do stuff
            incAmt += 0.9;
        }
```

I can't sleep the main thread and I cant use TimeUnit wait function.. I am lost :\

Comment: Why can't you use `Thread.sleep`?  Are you trying to run it within a GUI?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah.. its in a gui

Comment: If you're using Swing, I'd suggest using a SwingTimer instead

Comment: ok ill try to make something work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yeah.. its in a gui

For Swing, I'd recommend using a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dont be lost , start a new thread and put ur loop there , in that thread u can make it sleep for as long as u want without damaging ur main procedure